# How to get rid of the "Failed to update system registry" dialog for an application with normal user permissions

Tags: windows, permissions, administrator, regedit

I have an application which is modifying the Windows registry upon execution. With administrator privileges, the application executes fine (no problem) but whenever a normal user executes the application, a dialog box appears with following message

> Failed to update system registry. Please try using REGIDIT.

The application executes successfully when clicked on OK button. But I want to get rid of this message.

The problem is obviously with permissions.

The application is just standalone executable.

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Windows 7 : 
If you application needs Administrative privileges to run and you trust it, modify the properties for the executable to always execute as Administrator.
IRC, you right click on the executable, the option is at the bottom of the Compatibility tab.
- Also check if there is a newer version of your app that handles UAC correctly and can be run as regular user.

For Windows XP:
The RunAs utility can be used to start some programs under another privileges, you can get more information at:

http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/runas.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: Thanks. Not found any option related to change execution permission in compatibility tab. I am using XP.

Comment: Sorry about the confussion, I updated the answer with an option for running apps as administrator with WinXP

Answer (score 3):

Use [Sysinternals Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to see to where in the registry the application tries to access (as a normal user).

Set a filter to the process name and watch only registry activity (disable network,file, etc....)

Then look for the Access Denied messages (in the result column) and set permissions to those registry locations.

Please be careful....